# syntax error when using search in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, ajax, django-forms

I'm making a forms in Django and JavaScript

I need to display a form after clicking on a button, which will be answered and it will return (in JSON format) a list with the answers.

My code index.js

```
document.querySelector("#create-blank-form").addEventListener("click", () => {
    const csrf = Cookies.get('csrftoken');
    fetch('/form/create', {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {'X-CSRFToken': csrf},
        body: JSON.stringify({
            title: "Untitled Form"
        })
    })
    .then(response =>  response.json())
    .then(result => {
        window.location = `/form/${result.code}/edit`
    })
})
```

The error, the error points to .then(result...)

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
Promise.then (async)        
(anonymous)
```

My views.py

```
def create_form(request):
print('hi')
# Creator must be authenticated
# Create a blank form API
if request.method == "POST":
    print('hi')
    data = json.loads(request.body)
    title = data["title"]
    code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(30))
    choices = Choices(choice = "Option 1")
    choices.save()
    question = Questions(question_type = "multiple choice", question= "Untitled Question", required= False)
    question.save()
    question.choices.add(choices)
    question.save()
    form = Form(code = code, title = title, creator=request.user)
    form.save()
    form.questions.add(question)
    form.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "Sucess", "code": code})
```

My .html

```
<div class="form-template-box">
            <img src = "{% static 'Icon/blank-form.png' %}" alt = "Blank form" title = "Blank form" id="create-blank-form">
            <span class="form-template-label">Blank Form</span>
        </div>
```

my urls.py

```
path('form/create', views.create_form, name="create_form"),
```

**EDIT**

my problem was with the url, in urls.py, another part of my code was for some reason influencing in a bad way. thanks for the comments, they helped me find the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your function has some problems that return an error instead of JSON Response. So in `.then(response =>  response.json())` will raise error. You can try the sample below to check the error.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    try:
        print('hi')
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        title = data["title"]
        code = ''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters + string.digits) for x in range(30))
        choices = Choices(choice = "Option 1")
        choices.save()
        question = Questions(question_type = "multiple choice", question= "Untitled Question", required= False)
        question.save()
        question.choices.add(choices)
        question.save()
        form = Form(code = code, title = title, creator=request.user)
        form.save()
        form.questions.add(question)
        form.save()
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Sucess", "code": code})
    except Exception as err:
        return JsonResponse({"message": "Failed", "error": err})
```

And

```
.then(result => {
        console.log("DEBUG result: ", result);
        window.location = `/form/${result.code}/edit`
    })
```

Comment: I did that and nothing happened, it looks like it didn't even go to the view

Answer (score 0):

The error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` says that the first character of the response is '<' and suggests that the response given is in XML format rather than JSON.

So `response.json()` wont work becuase `response` is not valid JSON. if it were, the first character would be '{' or '['.

I would suggest you console.log() the response to check the format of it and then extract the 'code' element youre looking for using:

```js
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(response, 'text/xml');
const codeYouWant = doc.getElementsByTagName("code")[0].innerHTML;
```

Comment: I received this: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerHTML')

Answer (score 0):

my problem was with the url, in urls.py, another part of my code was for some reason influencing in a bad way.
thanks for the comments, they helped me find the error

Comment: You should edit your original post or comment directly to another comment